# Console view restriction by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there a policy action in IAM that will restrict the visibility of resources in the colnsole  to only a tagged set? So for example can i use ec2:Describe with a StringEquals condition for the tag such that a group of users will only ever see the set of EC2 servers their project is using?

Ideally i dont want all users in this VPC to see all servers regardless if they are read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not currently possible:

> **Note** Currently, the Amazon EC2 ec2:Describe* API actions do not
>   support resource-level permissions, so you cannot control which
>   individual resources users can view in the console. Therefore, the *
>   wildcard is necessary in the Resource element of the above statement.
>   For more information about which ARNs you can use with which Amazon
>   EC2 API actions, see Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon
>   EC2 API Actions.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

On option you have, that might work is to use multiple, independent AWS accounts, so each user can get there own 'sandbox' to play in, but setup consolidate billing so that that aspect of the accounts are all shared by one master account.